# How to tell Google Closure to drop variable initializations that are unused?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

My code is made of a few files and the default value may be overriden at initialization. By default, Google Closure Compiler will keep initializing with the default value though it is never used. Is there an equivalent to `@nosideeffects` so that the first variable definition is dropped.

Here is an example:

```
var a = 1;
a = 2;
window.console.log(a);
```

Will be compiled into (in advanced mode):

```
var a=1,a=2;window.console.log(a);
```

In my case, the default value is a pretty long string and I feel it's worth finding a way to tell the compiler to only keep the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Closure Compiler has several optimization that only run within function bodies (because they are too expensive to run on large projects):  "flow sensitive inlining" is the one you want here.  In simple mode, this:

```
function f() {
  var a = 1;
  a = 2;
  window.console.log(a);
}
```

becomes:

```
function f() {
  window.console.log(2);
}
```

There isn't anything you need to do to enable this except don't put your code in global scope.

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid it means it can't be done. In my case, I have a bunch of script level variables that are defined at the root in a header file (then wrapped together with the rest in a closure at compile time). For versionning my script, I overwrite those variables with `--define=XXXX`. But since objects can't be overwritten, I include a separate file to overwrite the objects (when need be) between the header and the script. I can't find a way to discard the header initialization... too bad

Comment: Won't be that simple but there is a way to have a variable `OVERRIDEN` and initialize only if not overriden but it means that I need to repeat something which I hate (the variable that overrides and the fact that I override)...